# enable/disable typedef with sfinae is impossible. Workarounds?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have different types of matrices and I want to create a generalized submatrix reference class `MatrixRef`.

Matrices implement only a few of members like `row(i)`, `column(i)`, `diagonal()` etc and of-course define the corresponding type `row_vector` etc.

On `MatrixRef` I want, if template parameter C has not define e.g. `col_vector`, `MatrixRef` doesn't define `col_vector` too. Or as workaround define it `void`.

For function members I found a working solution, but on typedefs not.

```
struct Matrix
{
    typedef vector<double>& row_vector;
    //typedef ColumnContainerReference col_vector;
    typedef DiagonalContainerReference diag_vector;

    row_vector row(size_type i);
    //col_vector col(size_type i);
    diag_vector diagonal();
};


template<typename C>
struct MatrixRef
{
    typedef typename C::row_vector row_vector;
    typedef typename C::col_vector col_vector;
    typedef typename C::diag_vector diag_vector;

    template<typename C1 = C>
    typename enable_if<is_matrix<C1>::has_rows, row_vector>::type
    row(size_type i);
    ...... col(size_type i);
    ...... diagonal();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a traits base class:

```
template<typename C, typename = void>
struct row_vector_alias_definer{ };

template<typename C>
struct row_vector_alias_definer<C,
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<typename C::row_vector, typename C::row_vector>::value
        >::type>
{
    typedef typename C::row_vector row_vector;
};
```

And then let your class derive from the appropriate instantiation of that traits template:

```
template<typename C>
struct MatrixRef : public row_vector_alias_definer<C>
{
    // ...
};
```

Same thing for other optional type aliases.